# Cannot properly format an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I need to place an algorithm inside my text. However, it keeps being displayed incorrectly.
Could you take a look at the LaTeX code and help me find where I am going wrong?

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,brazil]{report} 


\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\newcommand\BB{BB}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{The \BB algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State \BB(G, Q, K) 
\State $\text{C} \gets \text{Q}$ 
\If {$\text{K} \neq \emptyset$ }
\State $\text{v} \gets \text{a vertex in K}$
\State ${C_1 \gets BB(G, Q \cup \{v\}, U \cap \Gamma_G(v))$
\If {$|C_1| > |C|$}
\State $C \gets C_1$
\EndIf 
\State $C_2 \gets BB(G, Q, K - v)$
\If {$|C_2| > |C|$}
\State $C \gets C_2$
\EndIf
\EndIf
\Return $C$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What exactly is the problem? A full compilable code also would help to help. You seem to be using `babel-italian?

Comment: Thank you! I'm fairly new to the LaTeX platform. 
    \documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,brazil]{report}
    \usepackage{epsfig}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

Comment: You should add them in your post, and write a full minimal (non-)working example.  But what is the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is that the code is not being displayed properly. For example, the "Se |C2| > |C|" should be in a new line (it's the IF command, but in Portuguese"

Comment: your code generates errors `! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }`  after an error it is not worth even looking at the generated pdf, your question should have asked about the error not shown the output. Also If I run it, I get a line break before If and it says If not Se. I will add a document to your question but please edit it to show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After adding an missing closing bracket `}` in your code I can compile without error---and for me without missing line break!

Please see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,brazil]{report} 


\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\newcommand\BB{BB}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{The \BB algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State \BB(G, Q, K) 
\State $\text{C} \gets \text{Q}$ 
\If {$\text{K} \neq \emptyset$ }
\State $\text{v} \gets \text{a vertex in K}$
\State ${C_1 \gets BB(G, Q \cup \{v\}, U \cap \Gamma_G(v))}$
%                                                         ^  } added!
\If {$|C_1| > |C|$}
\State $C \gets C_1$
\EndIf 
\State $C_2 \gets BB(G, Q, K - v)$
\If {$|C_2| > |C|$}
\State $C \gets C_2$
\EndIf
\EndIf
\Return $C$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]